# C++ get the mangled names of a function/method

Tags: c++, g++, name-mangling

Hi I need to determine the mangled name of a function from within an c++ app itself.
Is there any equivalent to the `__FUNCDNAME__` macro in g++ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is documentation on the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Name Mangling Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491115/where-is-documentation-on-the-microsoft-visual-studio-c-name-mangling-scheme)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that - he's asking about how to do it in gcc.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that. Not a duplicate, but related maybe.

Answer (score 0):

To get the demangled name use __PRETTY_FUNCTION__.

Better is to use:

```
#include <boost/current_function.hpp>

BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION
```

This gives the demangled name. I looked at cxxabi.h but there does not seem to be a mangle function. Do you really want the mangled name?