# Getting mangled name from demangled name

Tags: c++, g++, name-mangling

Is there any way to get back the mangled name from demangled name in g++.

For example , I have the demangled name `func(char*, int)`, what should I do to get the mangled name i.e `_Z4funcPci` back?

My question is g++ specific.

Comment: @H2CO3: Great link, but is there any way to know if it's up-to-date and authoritative?  The domain name seems to be to a website at the University of Winnipeg.

Comment: @j_random_hacker American technical universities have the good habit of not putting junk on their official website(s).

Comment: @H2CO3: On the contents page that page links to: "This document was generated on 27 August 1999".  Also, Winnipeg is in Canada if I recall :-P

Comment: @j_random_hacker correct. I shoulda said 'american'. Well, let's try to find a newer version then.

Comment: @j_random_hacker also, this [related SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262585/c-get-the-mangled-names-of-a-function-method) points to the same site :)

Comment: @H2CO3: True.  I've now gone and rained on that answer's parade too.  :-/

Comment: See also answers in [compiler construction - What is Linux utility to mangle a C++ symbol name? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335624/what-is-linux-utility-to-mangle-a-c-symbol-name?noredirect=1&lq=1) ■ Reverse question:  [c++ - Function to mangle/demangle functions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939636/function-to-mangle-demangle-functions)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can simply use g++ to compile an empty function with the signature you require and extract the name from that. For example:

```
echo "int f1(char *, int) {} " | g++ -x c++ -S - -o- | grep "^_.*:$" | sed -e 's/:$//'
```

gives output

```
_Z2f1Pci
```

which is I think what you require. Make sure that you include any relevant header files as they will affect the way the symbols are mangled.

Comment: Good approach.  And use `c++filt` for the other direction.

Comment: It's not always that easy. Suppose you have names like `IFS::Profiler::create(IFS::Handle hdl)`.

Comment: exactly "not that easy". Compilation fails if any mentioned data structures are not declared. Some of them are in your code, some of them come from headers.

Answer (score 13):

Based on the Bojan Nikolic's approach, here's a better script:

*mangle.bash:*

```
IFS='::' read -a array <<< "$1"

indexes=("${!array[@]}")

prefix=""
middle=""
suffix=""
rettype=""
if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    rettype="void"
fi


for index in "${indexes[@]}"
do
    #echo "$index ${array[index]}"
    if [ $index == ${indexes[-1]} ]; then
    #echo "last"
    middle="$rettype ${array[index]};"
    elif [ -n "${array[index]}" ]; then
    #echo "not empty"
    prefix="${prefix}struct ${array[index]}{"
    suffix="${suffix}};"
    fi
done

#echo "$prefix$middle$suffix $rettype $1{}"
echo "$prefix$middle$suffix $rettype $1{}" | g++ -x c++ -S - -o- | grep "^_.*:$" | sed -e 's/:$//'
```

Use:

```
$ ./mangle.bash "abc::def::ghi()"
_ZN3abc3def3ghiEv
$ ./mangle.bash "abc::def::ghi(int i, char c)"
_ZN3abc3def3ghiEic
$ ./mangle.bash "abc::def::def(int i, char c)" constr
_ZN3abc3defC2Eic
$ ./mangle.bash "abc::def::~def()" destr
_ZN3abc3defD2Ev
```

But as to constructors and destructors, remember that there are C0 C1 C2 and D0 D1 D2 ones.

Comment: Cam you explain how your script takes in the second parameter (constr/destr)? I can' really see it in the code (I only see $1). Also, what are C0, C1 and C2 ctors/dtors?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance... Why is it better?

Comment: @jww try to get the mangled name for `abc::def::ghi()` with the original script

Comment: The script does only work with arguments of built-in types. Once you have custom types, you'll need to include the declarations in the header files in the temporary C++ code.

Comment: This solution is still incomplete because you don't handle complex argument types. I think including necessary headers is unavoidable in general case.

Answer (score 4):

What's worst, sometimes you ***cannot*** mangle a name because you must get more than one result.

See https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4323/4398 (there are multiple destructors in VFT, and all of them are demangled as `ClassName::~ClassName()`). (The same applies to constructors, I have seen C0 and C2 constructors.)

On the other hand, that answer references the Itanium ABI: https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.75.html#mangling-type where mangling is specified.

**The itanium-abi Haskell package: it did not work for me (May 2014)**

There is a Haskell package 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/itanium-abi
that promises both demangling and mangling, but I could run only the demangling:

Installation on Ubuntu Precise:

```
sudo aptitude install ghc
sudo aptitude install cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install itanium-abi
```

Then you run `ghci` and after `import ABI.Itanium` and `import Data.Either` you get:

```
Prelude ABI.Itanium Data.Either> cxxNameToText $ head (rights [ demangleName "_ZTI13QSystemLocale" ])
"typeinfo for QSystemLocale"
```

There is `mangleName`, but it takes a `DecodedName` which is a data structure rather than a string, and that data structure is produced only by `demangleName` (unless I overlooked something). Hopefully, this will get better in some future release.

**The clang code**

I did not try [the clang code](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ItaniumMangle_8cpp_source.html).