# What is the data type for a string?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

This is most likely a very stupid question, but in C++, what is the data type for a string?  I want to make the variable x = "Slim Shady".

Would I declare x as an int?  I have tried declaring it as a char, but when I cout the variable, it only gives the first letter.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely this is covered in tutorials .. somewhere? (And no, a string is more surely *not* an integer.)

Comment: `std::string` is what you use.

Comment: How would you use this in your code?  std::string x?  Also, if you say using namespace std, can you just say string x?

Comment: It's rudimentary, Really basic stuff. Just google "strings in c/c++" and you'd get thousands of resources.

Comment: @skateboard34 yes, you can just do that.

Comment: Please don't google "strings in c/c++", unless you're looking for strings in C. There's not language called C/C++, and C is not at all like C++. Google `std::string` instead.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This might be a noobie question, but I don't think it's a *bad* question.

Comment: @DeadMG: Agreed, and it's not so simple as to be obvious to a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the header file string

```
#include <string>
```

Then you will be able to use std::string

```
std::string x="Slim Shady"
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

You can also not use std::strings, if you dont want to use them althought they are your best option

You can use Char arrays or char pointer (C-strings)

```
char x[]="Slim Shady";
```

or

```
char* x="Slim Shady";
```

The auto keyword is a C++0x feature. You should stay away from it till you learn the C++ basics

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` is the best bet. But you can also use `auto`, as in `auto x = "Slim Shady!";`. This means that you don't have to figure out the type to use the expression.

Comment: *"This means that you don't have to figure out the type to use the expression."* - Until you need to do anything meaningful with it, in which case you'll need to know that the type is `char*` (or `const char*` depending on your compiler).

Comment: @EdS.: It *has* to be `char const*`. `char*` for a string literal is ill-formed.

Comment: Dont make a beginner start using auto

Comment: Instead he should use awful C array declarations, amirite?

Comment: @Xeo: You're right; the type is an array of const char.  However, the conversion from `const char[]` to `char*` is perfectly well defined, so it is not "ill-formed" as you say.  Modifying the data is simply undefined behavior.

Comment: @DeadMG: The problem is that the use of `auto` assumes you know what you are doing.  When you run into compilation errors due to type mismatches and everything is declared as `auto` you have no idea (as a beginner) as to what the hell is going on.  One should have a firm understanding of the type system before mucking around with `auto`.

Comment: And, to elaborate; this response doesn't tell the OP what the type of a string literal is.  It tells him/her to assign it to a string (which is a conversion) or use `auto` (which says nothing of the actual type).  S/he still doesn't know what the type of `"hello"` is.

Comment: In this case, ignorance is bliss.

Answer (score 2):

"Slim Shady" is constant literal of type `char[11]` which is convertible to `const char*`. You can also use it for initialization of any char arrays bigger than 11. See:

```
char a[] = "Slim Shady";
char a[11] = "Slim Shady";
const char* a = "Slim Shady";
char a[12] = "Slim Shady";
```

See this little code:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void printTypeName(T t)
{
   std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  printTypeName("Slim Shady");
  printTypeName<decltype("Slim Shady")>("Slim Shady");
}
```

You get (on gcc) [mangled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400105/getting-mangled-name-from-demangled-name) names:

```
PKc
A11_c
```

From what I know - the first is `const char*` the second is `char[11]`. This is easy to explain since when passing array of anything to function - it is converted to const pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just mean:

```
std::string x = "Slim Shady";
```