# What is the type of a string literal?

Tags: c++, string, literals, string-literals

I'm confused about the type of a string literal. Is it a `const char *` or a `const char`?

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451496/what-is-the-data-type-for-a-string/12452097#12452097 to similar question.

Comment: @Ken The only difference between C and C++ in this regard is the `const` qualifier. C treats it as a `char[N]` instead of `const char[N]`

Comment: @Prætorian in C a string like "Hello" is a pointer, also arrays and pointers adopt the arithmetic, you can assign "Hello" to a pointer in C.

Comment: @Ken, You can do that in C++. Arrays decay into pointers. Arrays don't offer arithmetic like pointers do.

Comment: @Ken, Here's proof they're arrays in C, using the same method Seth did for C++: http://liveworkspace.org/code/198d050af0d08a9fc86ac17c144d581d. If it was a pointer, the size would very likely not be 11. You can put one with a different length in there alongside the first if you want to eliminate weird pointer sizes.

Comment: I think it is `const char (&) [N]` instead.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is a `const char[N]` (which is *the same thing* as `char const[N]`), where `N` is the length of the string plus one for the terminating `NUL` (or just the length of the string if you define "length of a string" as already including the `NUL`).

This is why you can do `sizeof("hello") - 1` to get the number of characters in the string (including any embedded `NUL`s); if it was a pointer, it wouldn't work because it would always be the size of  pointer on your system (minus one).

Comment: To back it up, *A narrow
string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as deﬁned below, and has
static storage duration (3.7).*

Comment: Won't disagree. However, when a string constant is used in template matching it appears to be as `char [N]` (and not `char const[N]`), at least in one usage... The context is: I have templ. mem. func `func(T const &x)` instantiated as `A.func("string")` and it matches with T as `char [7]`. Odd. Or perhaps because the parameter x is a 'const ref to an array [7] of const char' the second const is removed as redundant, and the first is not part of T. g++ 4.6.3

Comment: @greggo: C string literals are `char[]`. C++ up to and including C++03 *allows* (but deprecates) assigning a string literal to a non-const `char*` as well, although C++ string literals were *always* `const`. Starting with C++11, assigning a string literal to a non-const `char *` is *disallowed* without explicit casting.

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks , you made it stick in my mind , just one question, in C is string literal convertible to char * ?

Comment: @SurajJain: *Any* array is "convertible" to a pointer to its first element. But you lose the ability to determine the size of the array via `sizeof`.

Answer (score 10):

`"Hello world"` is `const char[12]` (eleven characters plus `'\0'` terminator).

`L"Hello world"` is `const wchar_t[12]`.

Since C++14, `"Hello world"s` is `std::string`.

Since C++17, `"Hello world"sv` is `std::string_view`.

Also note the `u8""`, `u""` and `U""` string literal notations added by C++11, which specify UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoding, respectively. The encoding of non-qualified string literals (i.e. `""` and `L""`) is (and always was) implementation-defined.

Comment: Just a noob question: Does adding `s` to a string literal make it of type `std::string`? If not, why is it being used?

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi Indeed `""s` is a way to have a [std::string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator""s). You can have [user-defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) since C++11.

Comment: In cpp, doesn't a string literal implicitely convert to string if `string s = "abc;` is written. If Yes, then why is `""s` used?

Comment: @AjaySinghNegi There are several reasons. One is that there is no conversion taking place. The literal **is** of type `std::string`. This can make a difference e.g. in template context.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary string literals are of type `const char[n]`, i.e. "array of *n* `const char`", where *n* is the number of characters in the string, including the null terminator.
For example, the string literal `"foo"` is an lvalue of type `const char[4]` (*n* is `4` due to the null terminator at the end of the string).

It would be valid to write:

```cpp
const char* str = "foo";
```

... because of [array-to-pointer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Array-to-pointer_conversion), but the type of `"foo"` is still `const char[4]`.

There are other kinds of string literals with different types. Here is a comparison, taken from [Table 12: String literals](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#tab:lex.string.literal) in the C++ standard:

| Kind | Type | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ordinary string literal | array of *n* `const char` | `"ordinary string"` |
| wide string literal | array of *n* `const wchar_t` | `L"wide string"` |
| UTF-8 string literal | array of *n* `const char8_t` | `u8"UTF-8 string"` |
| UTF-16 string literal | array of *n* `const char16_t` | `u16"UTF-16 string"` |
| UTF-32 string literal | array of *n* `const char32_t` | `u32"UTF-32 string"` |

Ordinary raw string literals are also of type `const char[n]`. For example, a raw UTF-8 string literal `u8R"(raw)"` is of type `const char8_t[4]`.

#### Note on C++98 and C

In C++98, the type of string literals is non-`const`, same as in C. This behavior was deprecated in C++03 and the type was made `const` in C++11. However, string literals are non-`const` in C to this day.

For all intents and purposes, you should treat string literals as if they are `const`. Even if you're using an old version of C++, or you're using C, you are not allowed to modify the string, so adding an "unnecessary" `const` can prevent bugs.