# C++: type of "such strings". Making a function call like fun("str") work

Tags: c++, string, move-semantics

Disclaimer: this *is* going to be lame.

Two questions:

1. The part driven by curiosity: what is the exact type of a quote-marked string? Prevoiusly I thought that it's a C `char[]` string converted to `std::string` when it is needed, but some `type_traits` experiments revealed this:

   ```
   std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype ("string")>::value; -> true
   std::is_object<std::remove_reference<decltype ("string")>>::value; -> true
   std::is_same<decltype ("string"), std::string&>::value; -> false
   ```
2. The lame part: what type of argument should a function take to be able to deal with calls like `fun("str")`? The reason for this question is that the following example does not compile because of the `static_assert`:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   void fun (const T &what)
   {
       static_assert(sizeof(T) < 0, "Something unsupported");
   }

   void fun (std::string str)
   {
       std::cout << "Copied" << std::endl;
   }

   void fun (const std::string &str)
   {
       std::cout << "Lvalue" << std::endl;
   }

   void fun (std::string &&str)
   {
       std::cout << "Rvalue" << std::endl;
   }

   int main ()
   {
       fun ("str"); //static assertion failed
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   More over, commenting the template out causes

   ```
   error: call of overloaded 'fun(const char [4])' is ambiguous
   candidates are: [all three options]
   ```

   It does not seem ambiguous to me. Why does not it construct a temporary string and pass it by rvalue-reference?

Comment: Its a pointer to a constant (read-only) null-terminated (ending with `\0`) array of `char`s.

Comment: @barakmanos Why did the `type_traits` show that it is not a pointer, but it is an lvalue-reference to an object then?

Comment: In C++, the type of string literal `"Hello"` is `const char[6]` (an array of 6 elements of type `const char`). It's pointer-like behavior is due to the array-to-pointer standard conversion.

Comment: Re: ambiguous overloads. All three of your overloads would accept a temporary `std::string` object equally well - hence the ambiguity.

Comment: Well, okay, it's quite well-known. But why did the `type_traits` identify it as not an array and not a const object? I am quite curious about the things happening inside

Comment: About the overloads: how to eliminate this ambuguity then? I thought that temporary objects are typically passed by rvalue-refs

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517983/c-what-is-the-datatype-of-string-literal. And please post only one question at a time.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not a duplicate, that's why I reopened. There is a lot more to this question than answered by that one.

Comment: @hvd One of the two questions asked is a duplicate. The other should have been asked separately.

Comment: @Alex: An array is an object.

Comment: @juanchopanza That would make it too broad at best, still not a duplicate.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf. Indeed, I missed that. But you can not have an array reference

Comment: @Alex: C++ supports array references. I'm not sure how that plays out with the type trait checkers.

Comment: @Alex The one thing you can't have is arrays of references (arrays where each element is a reference). Did you perhaps read that at some point, and misremember it as saying you can't have references to arrays?

Comment: No, I did not know about the 'const char **(&)** [N]' notation and combined this with knowing that we can not have pointer references

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007986/c-pass-an-array-by-reference), however, makes me search some more info about **C++** arrays as they are still those C pointer-equivalent things in my mind

Comment: @Alex: You can have references to pointers.

Comment: Uh.. Well, I definitely misremember something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prevoiusly I thought that it's a C `char[]` string converted to `std::string` when it is needed

Close. It's a `const char []` converted to `std::string` when it is needed.

> The lame part: what type of argument should a function take to be able to deal with calls like `fun("str")`?

You can use `std::string`. You can use `const char (&) [N]`. You can use `const char *`. However...

> The reason for this question is that the following example does not compile because of the `static_assert`:

...you have to give overload resolution a chance. When you have

> ```
> template <typename T>
> void fun (const T &what)
> {
>     static_assert(sizeof(T) < 0, "Something unsupported");
> }
> ```

then even though string literals are implicitly convertible to `std::string`, you say that *this* function can accept string literals directly. When given the choice between a function taking a string literal after an implicit conversion, and a function taking a string literal directly, the function taking it directly will be called.

> More over, commenting the template out causes
>
> ```
> error: call of overloaded 'fun(const char [4])' is ambiguous
> candidates are: [all three options]
> ```

Choose between taking by value and by reference. It would be fine to have a single non-overloaded function taking `std::string` by value. It would also be fine to have two overloaded functions taking `std::string` by `const &` and by `&&` reference. But by value *and* by reference is too much, there is no reason to prefer one over the other then.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for pointing out conversion vs priority and passing by value vs passing by reference

Answer (score 3):

String literal `"str"` has type `const char[4]`. The most appropriate function for this argument is the template function because it does not require a conversion to std::string.