# typeid("") != typeid(const char*)

Tags: c++, c++17, rtti, string-literals

I'm making a C++ library which relies heavily on RTTI (customizable bridge to another language) and is very confused about string literal type.

This is a simple test I made to show the problem:

```
std::cout << typeid(const char*).name() << std::endl; // PKc
std::cout << std::any("").type().name() << std::endl; // PKc
std::cout << typeid("").name() << std::endl;          // A1_c
```

For me it looks like the first two print the type for `const char*`, but the last one is an array.

Why do results for `std::any("").type()` and `typeid("")` differ? Is there a way to get the first behavior, i.e. make results for string literals consistent (I use type identification to call different type handlers)?

P.S.: tests are done using Clang version 8.0.0-3 (tags/RELEASE_800/final) on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: `""` isn't a `const char*`, so they don't have matching types.  A `""` is a `const char[]`, an array of const char.

Comment: @Eljay Question isn't whether they are or shouldn't be different types. That's a premise of the question. The question is why `std::any("").type()` is not array (A1_c).

Comment: To add to @Eljay's comment: the 2nd line (`std::any`) is a pointer because the char array decays to a pointer when it's passed to the constructor.

Comment: @Timo it's passed by reference, so it doesn't decay when passed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the type of the string literal `""` is `const char[1]`, as explained by, e.g., [What is the datatype of string literal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517983/what-is-the-datatype-of-string-literal-in-c).

The type stored in `std::any("")` is `const char*` because you are using the following constructor (http://www.eel.is/c++draft/any.cons#8):

```
// Effects: Constructs an object of type any that contains an object of 
// type std::decay_t<T> direct-initialized with std::forward<T>(value).
template< class T>
any( T&& value );
```

In this case, `T` is `const char(&)[1]` (the type of the string literal `""`), and thus [`std::decay_t<const char(&)[1]>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) will give you `const char*`, which is why the `typeid()` of `std::any("").type()` is the type ID of `const char*`.

Comment: So what I want is to apply `std::decay` before `typeid`?

Comment: @val I don't really know what you want to do (not clear from your question), but if you create an object of type `std::decay_t<T>` from your object of type `T`, this should give you this behavior, similar to `std::any` behavior.

Answer (score 4):

> Why do results for `std::any("").type()` and `typeid("")` differ?

Accroding to the following [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any):

> ```
> template< class ValueType >
> any( ValueType&& value );
> ```
>
> 4) Constructs an object with initial content an object of type `std::decay_t<ValueType>`, direct-initialized from `std::forward<ValueType>(value)`.

`std::decay_t<const char[1]>` is `const char*`.

---

Here is a quote from FrankHB1989 on the [isocpp.org forum](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-proposals/cJD8urBWN7c/RHNaAThWDQAJ), which I think is relevant in understanding `std::any`, in context of this question:

> [`std::any`] is even not for "any object". As I have argued before, I have expect the word "any" being short for "any first-class object type" (i.e. cv-unqualified non-array object type), but `std::any` has additional refinement of CopyConstructible on the value type, so it is actually for "any copyable cv-unqualified non-array object type" instead.

As such

> Is there a way to get first behavior, i.e. make results for string literals consistent (I use type identification to call different type handlers)?

There is no way of having `std::any` of array (you can have `std::any` of `std::array`, but string literal is not a `std::array`), and there is no way of making `typeid("")` be a pointer. However, you can use `std::decay_t<decltype("")>` to get the same type as stored in `std::any`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common misconception that a string literal has type `const char*`.

It doesn't. It has type `const char[<size + 1>]` (plus one for the null terminator).

e.g. `""` has type `const char[1]`.

But we often assign a string literal to a `const char*`, out of convention (and also because otherwise we trigger special rules that result in *copying* the string).

Furthermore, array name decay rules actually make it quite hard to observe the array-ness of a name in C (and, by extension, C++); that `std::any` works the way it does is an example of that.