# What does "PKc", as the output of typeid(var).name(), mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm getting
`PKc` as the output when providing `typeid(check).name()` - where `check` is a `char` variable - as the argument to `typeid.name()`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{ 
    char check='e';
   cout<<typeid(check).name()<<"\n";
   cout<<typeid(typeid(check).name()).name();
}
```

output

```
c
PKc
```

Getting it even on changing the type of  `check` from `char` to `double`

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
main()
{ 
    double check=69.666;
   cout<<typeid(check).name()<<"\n";
   cout<<typeid(typeid(check).name()).name();

}
```

output

```
d
PKc
```

P.S. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin) suggested by @AsteroidsWithWings does provide the bare-bones of the underlying concepts but doesn't specifically answers what "PKc" means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typeid("") != typeid(const char\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564321/typeid-typeidconst-char)

Comment: Don't rely on `typeid.name()`, implementation of this function isn't standardized (library specific).

Comment: @AdrianMole No. I actually perused that question before asking this one

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does typeid.name() return weird characters using GCC and how to make it print unmangled names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PKc` is the [mangled name](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling-type) of `const char*`. `P` is the encoding for "pointer", `K` refers to "const", and `c` means "char".

See also [Why does typeid.name() return weird characters using GCC and how to make it print unmangled names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin).

Answer (score 0):

That string is returned from a `std::type_info::name()` function call. The result of that function is implementation-specific, that is the C++ standard does not require all compilers to return some specific string. Instead, each compiler is allowed to invent its own string representation of C++ type names. Compilers are not required to make that string easily readable.

Very likely, `"PKc"` is the string that your particular compiler is using to represent `const char*` type, which is the return type of `std::type_info::name()` function.

Comment: VSC != VS. Visual Studio is (I think) the only major compiler that actually returns human-readable names from `typeid(...).name()`.