# Why does const char[] get converted to const char* all the time?

Tags: c++, string-literals

So, I'm aware that a string literal has a type of `const char[N]`. And I'm also aware that if we got a `const char[]` parameter in some function, compiler automatically converts it to `const char*`.

But why do I always get compiler error messages saying that a string literal has a type of `const char*`?

Here's a few examples:

```
void f(int x) {}
int main()
{
    f("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR: `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int'`

```
void f() {
    throw "Hello";
}
int main()
{
    try{ f(); } catch (int x) { std::cout << "No\n";}
    return 0;
}
```

In terminal: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'`

EDIT: I'm using GNU GCC.

Comment: @Jabberwocky https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517983/what-is-the-datatype-of-string-literal-in-c

Comment: My compiler says `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [6]' to 'int' for 1st argument`

Comment: @GRRohman Right, so that link should answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the datatype of string literal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517983/what-is-the-datatype-of-string-literal-in-c)

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sadly, no .

Comment: I suspect it's a (small) gcc bug. The Microsoft compilers (at least recent versions) and clang produce the correct error message with respect to this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517983/what-is-the-datatype-of-string-literal-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does const char[] get converted to const char* all the time?

Generally, because there is another rule closely related to the function parameter adjustment that you mentioned:

> [conv.array] Array-to-pointer conversion
>
> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”.
>   The temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied.
>   The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.
>
> [basic.lval] Value category
>
> Whenever a glvalue appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, **array-to-pointer**, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.

Colloquially, this implicit conversion is called pointer *decaying*.

The error message appears to describe an attempt to convert this intermediary result of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to the parameter type.

> In terminal: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

In this particular case of exception throwing, there is a specific rule, which is essentially same as pointer decaying, but in context of a throw:

> [expr.throw]  Throwing an exception
>
> Evaluating a throw-expression with an operand throws an exception; **the type of the exception object is determined by** removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand and **adjusting the type from “array of T”** or function type T **to “pointer to T”**.

So, the adjusted type of the exception object is in fact `const char*`, and it is this uncaught object that the compiler generated message describes.

---

For completeness, here is the parameter adjustment rule that you knew:

> [dcl.fct] Functions
>
> ... After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”

P.S. there is also an analogous adjustment rule for exception handlers:

> [except.handle] Handling an exception
>
> A handler of type “array of T” or function type T is adjusted to be of type “pointer to T”.

Comment: This explains the exception messsage, but I don't see how this explains why gcc refers to the string literal as `const char*`, while msvc and clang refer to it (more correctly?) as `const char[6]`.

Comment: @churill GCC refers to the adjusted type of the thrown exception object, and Clang refers to the type of the expression before adjustment. In my opinion, both are correct and I don't think it's clear which is more useful.

Comment: @eerorika Does that "automatical" array-to-pointer conversion happen using temporary objects? If not , how does the conversion happen on slightly lower level ?

Comment: @domocar1 It does happen using temporary objects too.

Comment: Too ? What's the alernative ? I haven't caught it from your answer, maybe it is due to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @domocar1 alternative is non-temporaries. Such as the string literal in your example.