# C++ Name Mangler

Tags: c++, name-mangling

I need a command line mangler for gcc. C++filt will de-mangle

```
c++filt _ZN10NamespaceA7not_funEi
=> NamespaceA::not_fun( int )
```

But i need a mangler

```
mangler NamespaceA::not_fun( int )
=> _ZN10NamespaceA7not_funEi
```

How do I achieve this?

EDIT:
So the answer is. A mangler does not exist. I have to build my own.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400105/getting-mangled-name-from-demangled-name-g?rq=1 ?

Comment: You'd need an entire C++ parser. A gigantic task.