# get mangled symbol name from inside C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++

How can I get the mangled name of a function from inside a C++ program?

For example, suppose I have a header:

```
// interface.h
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H
typedef void (*FooFunc)(int x, int y, double z, ...more complicated stuff...);
void foo(int x, int y, double z, ...more complicated stuff...);
#endif
```

and I have a client program that can load plugins that implement the interface:

```
// client.h
#include "interface.h"
void call_plugin(so_filename)
{
    void *lib = dlopen(so_filename, ...);
    // HOW DO I IMPLEMENT THE NEXT LINE?
    static const char *mangled_name = get_mangled_name(foo);
    FooFunc func = (FooFunc)dlsym(lib, mangled_name);
    func(x, y, z, ...);
    dlclose(lib);
}
```

How do I write the `get_mangled_name` function to compute the mangled name of the `foo` function and return it as a string?

One method that comes to mind is to compile `interface.o` and use `nm -A interface.o | grep foo` to get the mangled name then copy-and-paste it as a hard-coded string into `client.h`, but that feels like the wrong approach.

Another method that comes to mind is to force `interface.h` to be a pure C interface where I marshal all of the C++ data into a big blob that's sent through a C interface and then have the C++ objects reconstructed on the other side.  This also feels suboptimal.

**Edit**

Note that this is actually a distinct question from [Getting mangled name from demangled name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12400105/25050).  I'm wondering how to get at the mangled value from inside of C++ itself, at compile time, from type information available to the compiler, given a C++ identifier's name only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting mangled name from demangled name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400105/getting-mangled-name-from-demangled-name)

Comment: Mangling is platform specific. That said, some platforms follow a fixed ABI quite stably, so you can implement the mangling rules yourself. Here are the [Itanium ABI mangling rules](https://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling).

Comment: g++ mangling rules are here:  http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gcc/gxxint_15.html.  That shouldn't be hard to implement.  The hard part is parsing the input - you even have to account for not mangling the name if it's declared as `extern "C"` - and if you're parsing source files that can happen well-removed from the method you're interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent mangling by declaring your functions as `extern "C"`:

```
// interface.h
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H
typedef void (*FooFunc)(int x, int y, double z, ...more complicated stuff...);
extern "C" void foo(int x, int y, double z, ...more complicated stuff...);
#endif
```

... and making sure you #include that header file in all the source files that make up your shared library, as this declaration affects both the definition and references to the relevant function emitted by the compiler. Note that your function signature can still use non-POD types, such as std::string.