# Why does GCC linker's -wrap option not work for me?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, wrapper

I'm trying to wrap a library function with the GCC linker option -wrap.
As far as I've read up, this should replace the symbol libfoo with __wrap_libfoo and give access to the original definition by __real_libfoo.

I've implemented it like this:

original.h

```
#ifndef ORIGINAL_H
#define ORIGINAL_H

void libfoo();

#endif //ORIGINAL_H
```

original.cpp

```
#include "original.h"
#include <iostream>

void libfoo()
{
  std::cout<<"Original libfoo called from original.cpp"<<std::endl;
  return;
};
```

And compiled to a static lib with `g++ --std=c++11 -c original.cpp -o liboriginal.o`, packed up with `ar rcs liboriginal.a liboriginal.o` and moved to a location known to the linker.

wrapper.h

```
#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

// should not need anything here

#endif //WRAPPER_H
```

wrapper.cpp

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include <iostream>

//forward declaration to suppress compiler error
void __real_libfoo();

void __wrap_libfoo()
{
  std::cout<<"Wrapper libfoo called from wrapper.cpp"<<std::endl;
  __real_libfoo();
  return;
};
```

Compiled again to a static lib with `g++ --std=c++11 -c wrapper.cpp -o libwrapper.o`, packed up with `ar rcs libwrapper.a libwrapper.o`.

main.cpp

```
#include "original.h"

int main()
{
  libfoo();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `g++ --std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o` and linked everything together with `g++ -L. -Wl,-wrap=libfoo -o test ./main.o -loriginal -lwrapper`

On execution, I only get
    Original libfoo called from original.cpp
at the console.

Why does the linker not replace the symbol so the call is redirected to `__wrap_libfoo()`?

And, if this is solved, how do I handle multiple, overloaded functions, which all should be wrapped? Do I need just one `-wrap=function_name` or do I need to somehow add a more detailed signature to the linker option?

**Update:** I've also tried not linking the wrapper as a lib, but as an object file instead. This gives me a undefined ref error from the linker regarding the missing __real_libfoo() implementation.

Comment: A problem here is that function names in C++ are *mangled*, and you pass the unmangled `libfoo` name to the linkers `wrap` option. Try to use e.g. `extern "C"` for all functions (the original, and the wrapped).

Comment: This indeed works and also answers my second question about the overloaded functions. But of course in the real world, I have no control over the original library code. Seems I need to figure out the name mangling instead. Care to make your comment into an answer?

Comment: You might want to check [Getting mangled name from demangled name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12400105/440558).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400105/getting-mangled-name-from-demangled-name how to mangle. Even when the mangled name is used for the linker option, the `extern "C"` has to be used in the wrapper.