# dlopen c++ library and dlsym call function with c++ style arguments

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have a C++ shared library with functions like

```cpp
extern "C" void myfunc(const std::string &foo, std::map<std::string>&bar)
```

I have a C++ program which uses `dlopen()` to LAZY_LOAD load the library and then `dlsym()` to load `myfunc`. However, I am confused by the fact that the linker was told to use C style linking with C++ STL style arguments. How does that work? Won't that corrupt the stack?

Comment: AIUI, the only effect this has -- at least on Linux -- is to prevent name-mangling by the compiler/linker. This allows the symbol to be found by the linker even if the library and program are compiled with a different compiler, though in that case I'd be a bit worried that their `std::string` and `std::map` implementations are incompatible. tl;dr the arguments are likely passed just fine, but the two things might disagree about what a string/map looks like.

Comment: @cdhowie - in my case, both the shared library and the executable are compiled with the same compiler. It is on Linux.

Comment: In that case, the name mangling should be compatible and you don't need to declare the function with C linkage.

Comment: @cdhowie That would require passing the mangled name to `dlsym`, no?

Comment: @PaulSanders That is true. Of course, the mangled name can be determined rather easily. ([Example with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12400105/501250))